# Gstreamer deleting a queue branch causes other branches to pause

Tags: c, gstreamer

I control video recording by connecting and disconnecting branches, but in a small probability, appsrc will refuse data and cannot continue to work. I don’t know what caused it. Tell me if you have a solution or other control methods ?
this is the pipeline:

[pipeline vision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0oPa.png)

and this is the function to control video:

```c
void GstHandle::startRecord(QString path)
{
    if(mIsRecording){
        log_info("%s : GST current record is already open", __func__);
        return;
    }
    record_start = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    mRecordQueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "record_queue");
    mH264Parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "myparse");
    mQtMux = gst_element_factory_make("qtmux", "qtmux");
    mFileSink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "filesink");

    if(!mFileSink || !mRecordQueue || !mQtMux || !mH264Parse){
        log_error("%s : GST create elements error", __func__);
        return;
    }

    g_object_set (mFileSink, "location", path.toLocal8Bit().data(), NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(mPipeline), mRecordQueue, mH264Parse, mQtMux, mFileSink, NULL);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(mFileSink);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(mQtMux);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(mH264Parse);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(mRecordQueue);
    if(gst_element_link_many(mRecordQueue, mH264Parse, mQtMux, mFileSink, NULL) != TRUE)
    {
        log_error("%s : GST video queue link error", __func__);
    }

    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(mRecordQueue);

    //set pads
    tee_record_pad = gst_element_get_request_pad(mTee, "src_2");
    record_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mRecordQueue, "sink");
    if(!tee_record_pad || !record_sink_pad){
        log_error("%s : GST get pads error", __func__);
        return;
    }
    GstPadLinkReturn ret = GST_PAD_LINK_OK;
    if(!gst_pad_is_linked(record_sink_pad)){
        ret = gst_pad_link(tee_record_pad, record_sink_pad);
        if(ret != GST_PAD_LINK_OK)
        {
            log_error("%s : GST pad link error", __func__);
            gst_object_unref(record_sink_pad);
            return;
        }
    }
    gst_object_unref(record_sink_pad);

    if(gst_element_set_state(mPipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        log_error("%s : GST Unable to set the pipeline to playing state!", __func__);
    }
    mIsRecording = true;
    log_info("%s : GST start record, save %s", __func__, path.toLocal8Bit().data());
}

void GstHandle::stopRecord()
{
    if(!mIsRecording){
        return;
    }

    if(gst_element_send_event(mQtMux, gst_event_new_eos()) != TRUE){
        log_error("%s : GST send eos to qtmux error, may mp4 cannot play", __func__);
    }

    gst_element_set_state(mRecordQueue, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_element_set_state(mH264Parse, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_element_set_state(mQtMux, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_element_set_state(mFileSink, GST_STATE_NULL);

    record_sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(mRecordQueue, "sink");

    if(gst_pad_is_linked(record_sink_pad))
        gst_pad_unlink(tee_record_pad, record_sink_pad);
    gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(mPipeline), mFileSink);
    gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(mPipeline), mQtMux);
    gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(mPipeline), mH264Parse);
    gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(mPipeline), mRecordQueue);
    gst_object_unref(record_sink_pad);
    gst_element_release_request_pad(mTee, tee_record_pad);
    gst_object_unref(tee_record_pad);

    mIsRecording = false;
    log_info("%s : GST stop record", __func__);
}
```

I can't reproduce it stably, I would like to ask what are the possible situations or how to optimize this function. Thankyou very much!

Comment: Olny when I call stop function， it may happen.

Comment: How did you draw such pipelines(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0oPa.png)? I mean what tools did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance stop/start record can be accessed from multi-threads? If so, its does not seem to be thread-safe. 'mIsRecording' definition is not in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Both functions work on the same thread, and mIsRecording is a private variable in the class.

Comment: When I call the stop function, the pipe's appsrc signals enough-data and stops working. I was wondering if there was something wrong with the implementation of the stop function